In plain TeX (not LaTeX), how to create a ruled table that contains verbatim texts?
In plain TeX (not LaTeX), how to create a ruled table that contains verbatim texts?
The desired table is shown here.

Note: The desired table is now revised to explicitly show the C code that includes braces { } and preserves blank lines/spaces/tabs/indentations for Algo 1.

See https://www.volkerschatz.com/tex/halign.html and also https://ctan.org/pkg/stables maybe ...

Welcome … and: what have you tried, where do you struggle?



\def\hd{\bf\noindent\strut}
\def\v{\begingroup
  \obeylines
   \tt
  \catcode`\&12 %
  \catcode`\\12 %
  \catcode`\^12 %
  \catcode`\_12 %
  \startv}
\long\def\startv#1/endv{\vskip5pt#1\endgroup\vskip2pt}
\halign{%
  \vrule\vtop{\parindent0pt\hsize5cm\relax#}\vrule&&%
        \vtop{\parindent0pt\hsize5cm\relax#}\vrule\cr
  \noalign{\hrule}%
  \hd Algo 1  &\hd Algo 2 &\hd Algo 3\cr
  \noalign{\hrule}%
  \v
  verbatim & j \ggg
  source code
  /endv
  &
  \v
  verbatiim & j \ggg
  source code
  2
  /endv
  &
  \v
  verbatiiim \& j \ggg
  source code
  3
  /endv
  \cr
  \noalign{\hrule}%
  \strut$O(1)$ & $O(n)$ & $O(n^2)$
  \cr
    \noalign{\hrule}%
}

\bye


Maybe add some padding between the vertical rules and the text in the cells ...?

@JasperHabicht sure but it makes more sense to use a format with support for tables or verbatim or document production generally. this is a minimal example just showing basic use, which is all plain tex was ever intended to do.

@DavidCarlisle you have a \vrule too much in the first column's template.

@Skillmon fixed thanks

@DavidCarlisle. Upvoting for your excellent answer, thank you.

@Skillmon. Upvoting for your excellent answer, thank you.

Similar to @DavidCarlisle's answer with a few notable differences:

The verbatim code is in \cvrb...\endvrb, \cvrb has to be the last token on its line, and \endvrb has to be the first on its line (no spaces in front of it)
The verbatim block doesn't gobble leading spaces from each line.
The verbatim block is vertically centred
The verbatim block has the width of the longest natural width among its lines
The columns are at natural width
horizontal padding around the vertical rules

\def\cvrb{\begingroup
  \tt
  \def\\##1{\ifx\relax##1\else\catcode`##1=12 \expandafter\\\fi}%
  \\\\\{\}\$\&\#\^\_\%\~\relax
  \catcode`\ =13
  \lccode`\~=`\ %
  \lowercase{\def~}{ }%
  \catcode`\^^M=13
  \lccode`\~=`\^^M
  \lowercase{\def~}{\egroup\hbox\bgroup\strut}%
  \startvrb}

\begingroup
\lccode`\~=`\^^M
\catcode`\/=0
\catcode`\\=12
/lowercase{/endgroup
/def/startvrb~#1~\}endvrb%
  {$\vcenter{\hbox\bgroup\strut#1\egroup}$\endgroup}

\halign{%
    \vrule\hskip.5em\strut\ignorespaces#\ifhmode\unskip\fi\hfil\hskip.5em\vrule
    &&\hskip.5em\strut\ignorespaces#\ifhmode\unskip\fi\hfil\hskip.5em\vrule\cr
  \noalign{\hrule}
  \bf Algo 1 & \bf Algo 2 & \bf Algo 3\cr
  \noalign{\hrule}
\cvrb
/* C code (using {...}) */

int  i=10, j=8;
char *cc, d[8];

while(i>0)  // loop
  {
  i--;
  j=i^ (j&0x3f)<<1;
  }
\endvrb & \cvrb
verbatim
python code
\endvrb & \cvrb
verbatim
unix script
\endvrb\cr
  \noalign{\hrule}
  $O(1)$ & $O(n)$ & $O(2^n)$\cr
  \noalign{\hrule}
}
\bye



Would've answered this yesterday evening, but I fell asleep when I brought my two youngest children to bed :(
